IntelliSense Doesn't Update Automatically for Generated Files in Visual Studio C++ Project
I'm encountering an issue with IntelliSense in Visual Studio where it doesn't automatically update its database after a rebuild when using a custom NuGet package that generates .cpp and .hpp files during the build process.
Context:
In my C++ project, I use a NuGet package with a custom .targets file. This .targets file runs a tool during the build process (via an  task) that takes several input files, processes them, and generates two files: generated.cpp and generated.hpp. These files are then included in the project using ClInclude and ClCompile.
The input files define classes and members that my project uses, and the generated headers are included in my code. The build process itself works fine, and IntelliSense initially recognizes these files as expected.
Problem:
If I change something in one of the input files (e.g., add a new member to a class), rebuild the project, and then try to use the new member in my code, IntelliSense doesn't recognize the change. It shows errors for the new member as if the header hasn't been updated.
The only ways I’ve found to fix this are:
Manually open the generated.cpp file, right-click, and choose "Rescan file".
Rescan the entire solution or delete the IntelliSense database manually.
Neither of these is a practical solution for development.
Minimal Example:
Here’s a simplified example of the setup:
Input Files
TestInput.file (used as input to the tool during the build process)
#pragma once
class Test 
{
public:
    const static int test1 = 1;
    const static int test2 = 2;
    const static int test3 = 9000;
};

Generated Files (produced by the tool):
generated.hpp
#pragma once
class Test 
{
public:
    const static int test1 = 1;
    const static int test2 = 2;
    const static int test3 = 9000;
};

Dummy Generator Targets File (target file get's referenced from main Project)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
    <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
    <PropertyGroup />
    <ItemDefinitionGroup />
    <ItemGroup>
        <InputFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\*Input.File"/>
        <UpToDateCheckInput Include="@(ProtoFiles)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DummyGenerator" Inputs="@(InputFiles)" Outputs="%(InputFiles.rootdir)%(InputFiles.directory)%(InputFiles.filename).h" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Exec Command="copy %(InputFiles.Identity) @(InputFiles->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename).h')" Condition="%(InputFiles.Identity) != ''" />
        <ItemGroup>
            <ClInclude Include="@(InputFiles->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename).h')" Condition="%(InputFiles.Identity) != ''" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

</Project>



After modifying TestInput.file (for example by adding a new class member) and rebuilding which just copies TestInput.file to TestInput.h, Intellisense will not recognize the new member in the test Class until told to manually rescan.
Gitub to full example Project
Question:
How can I configure Visual Studio or modify my setup so that IntelliSense automatically updates its database to reflect changes in the generated .hpp files after a rebuild? Ideally, I want IntelliSense to rescan the affected files without manual intervention.
I’ve tried several approaches to make IntelliSense automatically recognize updates to the generated files after a rebuild. Some of the things I’ve tried include:

Modifying the .targets file to ensure the generated files are marked as updated, such as touching the files after they are generated.
Attempting to hook the generation task into design-time build targets (I’m not sure which ones specifically to use).
Experimenting with various project settings and IntelliSense configurations.
Restarting Visual Studio 2019 after making changes.
Generating TLogs using the GetOutOfDateItems task to track dependencies.
Unfortunately, none of these attempts worked. IntelliSense continues to show outdated information unless I manually rescan the files or rebuild the entire IntelliSense database, which is impractical and time-consuming.

I expected IntelliSense to automatically pick up changes to the generated.hpp and generated.cpp files after the build, just as it does for regular source files I edit inside the IDE.

Did you check  if #include paths are correct ? For more information, you can read Configure a C++ project for IntelliSense. Besides, try to delete .vs folder then reload your project to see if the issue persists.

@DouXu-MSFT
The specific include path for the generated.hpp files are added via the  property (set in the .targets file).
Also Intellisense can see the files and shows completions for them just fine it just dosn't automaticlly rescan the generated.h file if it changes
Deleting the .vs folder would be the same as delting the Intelisense database => it would rescan everything once but any further changes to the generated files would still need a manual rescan (or delting the .vs folder again) every time generated.h changes due to changes in input.h

Suggestions to troubleshoot: 1.Please check if you set Disable Database Updates and Disable Database Auto Updates to true in Tools->Options->C++->Advanced->Browsing/Navigation. 2.Manually add the generated files into the build process by adding the new file to the Content or None items before the BeforeBuild target. 3 If it possible, could you please provide a Minimal, Reproducible sample to help me reproduce?

@DouXu-MSFT Disable Database Updates and Disable Database Auto Updates are both set to false.
Adding the files to Content (at least from the NugetPackage) does not seem to help, the generated files still don't show up in VS and still won't auto update for Intellisense. Manually including them directly in the project file is not really practicle since I want any new input files (there are multiple input files) input.file along with their generated files to be added automatically.

@DouXu-MSFT I've uploaded a full minimal sample project, to reproduce the issue modify the class in TestInput.File or TestInput2.File (adding/removing/renamig members) and rebuild the project. Intelligence will not see the changes in TestInput.h/Test2Input.h until told to rescan.

Looks like i cannot reach this link you shared. Is it public?

@DouXu-MSFT It should be public, I can definitely reach it even from an external connection and without being logged in.
It's self hosted so it may not be 100% reliable all the time, maybe it was down when you tried?
If it still doesn't work I may have to upload it somewhere else.

Tried again and the same result. If possible, could you please upload a minimal sample project to public repo like GitHub?

@DouXu-MSFT ok, I've put the example up on Github and replaced the old link with a github link

After cloning your sample code to my local VS2022(17.12.3), unfortunately, i could not reproduce this issue. The intellisense can  recognize the new member in the test Class. Please check the test result:
(Add a new class member Animal in TestInput.file)

I have noted this doc Configure a C++ project for IntelliSense says,

To keep the IntelliSense database in sync with the code, Visual Studio automatically launches IntelliSense-only builds as background tasks in response to certain changes made in the project settings or source files.
However, in some cases Visual Studio might not update the IntelliSense database in a timely manner.

Suggestions:

You can force a rescan of all files in a solution by right-clicking on the project node in Solution Explorer and choosing Rescan Solution.

I guess this feature is not working for all cases. I would suggest you can submit a feature request at Visual Studio Forum.That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

I tried it again with Visual Studio 2022 I don't have the issue, maybe it's specific to Visual Studio 2019?

Tested in Visual Studio 2019 i don't have this issue. Maybe some cache or something wrong or as MS document says "in some cases Visual Studio might not update the IntelliSense database in a timely manner". I would suggest you report this issue at here to confirm the root cause.

The force rescan fix actually does work, the problem is that it's not detecting the change on it's own, having the rescan the solution every time I make a change to the Input Files is annoying.
Testing again  on my personal machine with VS2022 I partially reproduced the problem (It dosn't immdiatly see the change) except there it seems like restarting Visual Studio fixes things. And also reducing the rescan interval in the setting from 60 minutes to 1 get's it to see the changes pretty quckly (not ideal becouse in real work rescanning takes more then one minute)

I just don't know what I should put into that feature request/report, especially without a way for someone else to reproduce the issue.

Okay, i understand your concern. Sorry that no better suggestions to troubleshoot. Let's see if other community members have good ideas.
